# CASE function in SQL Server 2012 got error message

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Can somebody here help me?

I am trying to use `CASE` function as below got error message said

> message 156 incorrect syntax near keyword 'CASE'.

Thanks,

```
select distinct 
    FiscalYear 
    case
       when FiscalYear = '2014' 
          then 'FY2014/2015'
       when FiscalYear = '2015' 
          then 'FY2015/2016'
       when FiscalYear = '2016' 
          then 'FY2016/2017'
       else 'FY2017/2018'
    end
from  
    DimDate
order by 
    FiscalYear
```

Comment: Missing comma `select FiscalYear,..`

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing comma after `FiscalYear`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FiscalYear, --here
                CASE
                  WHEN FiscalYear = '2014' THEN 'FY2014/2015'
                  WHEN FiscalYear = '2015' THEN 'FY2015/2016'
                  WHEN FiscalYear = '2016' THEN 'FY2016/2017'
                  ELSE 'FY2017/2018'
                END
FROM   DimDate
ORDER  BY FiscalYear
```

however we can simplify your query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT FiscalYear,
                CASE
                  WHEN FiscalYear IN ( '2014', '2015', '2016' ) THEN Concat('FY', FiscalYear, '/', FiscalYear + 1)
                  ELSE 'FY2017/2018'
                END
FROM   DimDate
ORDER  BY FiscalYear
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no need for the CASE.  You'll have to edit the logic for years to follow.

```
Declare @YourTable table (FiscalYear varchar(10))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2014'),
('2015'),
('2016'),
('2017')

Select Distinct FiscalYear = concat('FY',FiscalYear,'/',1+FiscalYear)
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
FiscalYear
FY2014/2015
FY2015/2016
FY2016/2017
FY2017/2018
```

Comment: Other than 2014,2015 and 2016 OP's query will return `'FY2017/2018'` as default but it is not case in your answer.

Comment: @Prdp Fair enough.  Makes me wonder what else is in OP's field FiscalYear

Comment: Thanks for your response!